# ElasticSearch not returning the document with word prefixed or suffixed with dot or #

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

search query formed for searching the documents with given skills.

---

```
     GET resume_index/_search
        {
           "query": {
              "bool" : {
            "must" : [ {
              "ids" : {
                "types" : [],
                "values" : [ "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", "182", "183", "184", "185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190", "191", "192", "193", "194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", "200", "201", "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", "209", "210", "211", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", "218", "219", "220", "221", "222", "223", "224", "225", "226", "227", "228" ]
              }
            }, {
              "bool" : {
                "should" : [ {
                  "match" : {
                    "skills" : {
                      "query" : "c#",
                      "type" : "phrase",
                      "analyzer" : "synonym"


                    }
                  }
                }, {
                  "match" : {
                    "skills" : {
                      "query" : "asp.net",
                      "type" : "phrase",
                      "analyzer" : "synonym"

                    }
                  }
                } ],
                "minimum_should_match" : "1"
              }
            }, {
              "match" : {
                "skills" : {
                  "query" : "c#",
                  "type" : "phrase",
                   "analyzer" : "synonym"


                }
              }
            } ]
          }
           }
        }
```

---

Result is coming when i replace c# with other skill like java. But if c# or .net is mentioned in search query it is result is comin blank even those skills are already indexed.

---

```
  {
       "took": 11,
       "timed_out": false,
       "_shards": {
          "total": 5,
          "successful": 5,
          "failed": 0
       },
       "hits": {
          "total": 3,
          "max_score": 0.40027505,
          "hits": [
             {
                "_index": "resume_index",
                "_type": "phrase",
                "_id": "198",
                "_score": 0.40027505,
                "_source": {
                   "content": "",
                   "skills": [
                      "10g",
                      "c++",
                      "crystal report",
                      "ms-access",
                      "real estate",
                      "ui",
                      ".net",
                      "ado",
                      "c#",
                      "database",
                      "java",
                      "mvc",
                      "oracle 10g",
                      "order management",
                      "software development life cycle",
                      "system development",
                      "technica",
                      "vb",
                      "web technologies",
                      "windows xp",
                      "wpf",
                      "c",
                      "client management",
                      "development and maintenance",
                      "development life cycle",
                      "html",
                      "jquery",
                      "mysql",
                      "oracle",
                      "r",
                      "software development",
                      "ssrs",
                      "testing",
                      "unit testing",
                      "wcf",
                      "web applications",
                      "asp.net",
                      "asp.net mvc",
                      "c programming",
                      "deployment",
                      "management",
                      "project",
                      "sales",
                      "windows",
                      "adobe photoshop",
                      "developing",
                      "java script",
                      "reports",
                      "script",
                      "silverlight",
                      "software development life cycle (sdlc)",
                      "sql",
                      "sql server"
                   ]
                }
             },
             {
                "_index": "resume_index",
                "_type": "phrase",
                "_id": "199",
                "_score": 0.3792688,
                "_source": {
                   "content": "",
                   "skills": [
                      "application maintenance",
                      "client-server",
                      "cms",
                      "design",
                      "dos",
                      "e-commerce",
                      "erp",
                      "features",
                      "finance",
                      "knockout.js",
                      "mongodb",
                      "post-implementation",
                      "stocks",
                      ".net",
                      "ado",
                      "application development",
                      "c#",
                      "debugging",
                      "documentation",
                      "insurance",
                      "integration",
                      "java",
                      "mvc",
                      "planning",
                      "software development life cycle",
                      "svn",
                      "technica",
                      "agile",
                      "android",
                      "architecture",
                      "automation testing",
                      "client management",
                      "coordination",
                      "development life cycle",
                      "functional specification",
                      "healthcare",
                      "html",
                      "iis",
                      "jquery",
                      "networking",
                      "requirement gathering",
                      "software development",
                      "testing",
                      "tfs",
                      "triaging",
                      "troubleshooting",
                      "visual source safe",
                      "wcf",
                      "xcode",
                      "xml",
                      "asp.net",
                      "channel",
                      "css",
                      "entity framework",
                      "implementation and testing",
                      "maintenance support",
                      "management",
                      "mobile application",
                      "oracle forms",
                      "project",
                      "sales",
                      "sdlc",
                      "technical support",
                      "windows",
                      "ajax",
                      "analytics",
                      "client interaction",
                      "code management tool",
                      "crm",
                      "customer",
                      "excellent communication",
                      "ipad",
                      "java script",
                      "linq",
                      "market",
                      "ms dos",
                      "reporting"
                   ]
                }
             },
             {
                "_index": "resume_index",
                "_type": "phrase",
                "_id": "208",
                "_score": 0.3556832,
                "_source": {
                   "content": "",
                   "skills": [
                      "c++",
                      "control system",
                      "design",
                      "features",
                      "real estate",
                      ".net",
                      "ado",
                      "c#",
                      "database",
                      "integration",
                      "java",
                      "mvc",
                      "rdlc",
                      "stored procedures",
                      "technica",
                      "test case",
                      "agile",
                      "architecture",
                      "automation testing",
                      "banking",
                      "c",
                      "debug",
                      "design patterns",
                      "excel",
                      "iis",
                      "jquery",
                      "object oriented programming",
                      "r",
                      "security",
                      "software development",
                      "t-sql",
                      "testing",
                      "unit testing",
                      "wcf",
                      "web applications",
                      "xml",
                      "asp.net",
                      "c programming",
                      "css",
                      "development methodologies",
                      "entity framework",
                      "management",
                      "project",
                      "rdlc reports",
                      "sales",
                      "triggers",
                      "windows",
                      "ajax",
                      "coding",
                      "customs",
                      "dbms",
                      "developing",
                      "java script",
                      "javascript",
                      "linq",
                      "reporting",
                      "reports",
                      "schemas",
                      "script",
                      "software engineering",
                      "sql",
                      "sql server",
                      "telerik",
                      "test case design",
                      "visual studio",
                      "web service",
                      "webform",
                      "webforms"
                   ]
                }
             }
          ]
       }
    }
```

Content section i have removed because of max character allowed.
You can see that c# is indexed in document but still not able to get the result.

---

```
Query Analysis Looks ok to me.    

 {
       "valid": true,
       "_shards": {
          "total": 1,
          "successful": 1,
          "failed": 0
       },
       "explanations": [
        {
             "index": "resume_index",
             "valid": true,
             "explanation": "+ConstantScore(_uid:txt#176 _uid:txt#177    _uid:txt#178  _uid:txt#179 _uid:txt#180 _uid:txt#181 _uid:txt#182 _uid:txt#183  _uid:txt#184 _uid:txt#185 _uid:txt#186 _uid:txt#187 _uid:txt#188 _uid:txt#189 _uid:txt#190 _uid:txt#191 _uid:txt#192 _uid:txt#193 _uid:txt#194 _uid:txt#195 _uid:txt#196 _uid:txt#197 _uid:txt#198 _uid:txt#199 _uid:txt#200 _uid:txt#201 _uid:txt#202 _uid:txt#203 _uid:txt#204 _uid:txt#205 _uid:txt#206 _uid:txt#207 _uid:txt#208 _uid:txt#209 _uid:txt#210 _uid:txt#211 _uid:txt#212 _uid:txt#213 _uid:txt#214 _uid:txt#215 _uid:txt#216 _uid:txt#217 _uid:txt#218 _uid:txt#219 _uid:txt#220 _uid:txt#221 _uid:txt#222 _uid:txt#223 _uid:txt#224 _uid:txt#225 _uid:txt#226 _uid:txt#227 _uid:txt#228) +((skills:asp.net skills:c#)~1) +skills:c#"
          }
       ]
    }
```

I can see queries getting formed properly. Is something , i am missing which is causing this issue. I am using whitespace tokenizer

Answer (score 0):

I can see query-time analysis appears to work correctly, but how are you analyzing at index time? The default [standard tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html) tokenizes on `#` and `.` which would cause a `c#` query not to match, as shown here:

```
curl -XGET http://192.168.12.5:9200/tmdb/_analyze?analyzer=standard -d 'c#'
{
     "tokens":[
         {"token":"c",
          "start_offset":1,
           "end_offset":2,
           "type":"<ALPHANUM>",
           "position":1
 }]}
```

You can switch to the [simple analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-simple-analyzer.html) which just tokenizes on whitespace. You could also use the [mapping char filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html) to map things like `c#` => `csharp`.

Comment: Hi Doug, you can see the token in response in coming as c not c#. I tried with simple analyzer as well. we are using synonym analyzer with whitespace tokenizer. "analyzer": {
                  "synonym": {
                     "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "synonym"
                     ],
                     "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                  }
               }

Comment: @Ranveer yes to be clear I was pointing out a potential prob if you were using the standard analyzer. It appears you are not, and the analyzer you describe makes sense. 

Can you post the output of _analyze?field=skills passing C# above? You might also want to check out elyzer that helps with debugging analyzers https://github.com/o19s/elyzer

Comment: Thanks for your support. I was not indexing skills with synonym analyzer only content attribute was indexed using Synonym analyzer.